# Auto redirect based on http or https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write an htaccess rule. I have succeeded in it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*RSS/CATALOG [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

But here i would like to modify the RewriteRule. Here i need to autodetect http/https and then redirect. But not succeeded. Please help.

Comment: shame on whoever downvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*RSS/CATALOG [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*RSS/CATALOG [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```